# regex: match a pattern between last occurence of a "/" and the end of the line

Tags: regex, grep

I can't figure out how to match a pattern between LAST / and the end of the line.
I have tons of:
/usr/etc/blabla:/etc/**bbb**
/usr/etc/blabla:/etc/**bffb.gh**
/usr/etc/blabla:/local/**fffusr**
/usr/etc/blabla:/bin/**dfusrd**
/usr/etc/var:/etc/**aaaaaf.ju**

For example i want to match "usr" only when it is in the bold part.
I'm using grep.

EDIT:
I've a small problem with this solution:
/([^/]+)$
It doesn't match the pattern if it is immediately after the /, for example those:
/usr/etc/blabla:/bin/usrlala
/bin/bla/:/etc/usr
are not matched

FOUND IT: /([^/]*)$

Comment: [When asking regex questions, always add tag for the specific programming language or tool (e.g., Perl, Python, or Java; vi, emacs, or ɢɴᴜ grep; etc.) you are using.](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info)

Comment: waht, how does this solution find the entries with "usr" ????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be:

```
/([^/]+)$
```

But maybe you must escape the slash (`/`) depending on your language:

```
/\/([^\/]+)$/
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to use regex on such simple task?

If you're using php you can use

```
$pos = strrpos($line, '/');
```

to determine last occurance of / and then copy everything from there

```
$name = substr($line, $pos+1);
```

**regex is not ultimate solution to everything.** It will be slower on such simple string operations. Well, it will always be slower to your own procedure parsing a string (if it's written good).

Comment: +1: I'd do it this way in `zsh`: `for line in $(cat input.txt); echo ${line:t}`.
Regular expression are not the be all and end all.

Comment: i need it to do a grep in a large amount of text file

Comment: So it's even more of a reason NOT to use regex. Just loop through all lines.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "
/usr/etc/blabla:/etc/bbb
/usr/etc/blabla:/etc/bffb.gh
/usr/etc/blabla:/local/fffusr
/usr/etc/blabla:/bin/dfusrd
/usr/etc/var:/etc/aaaaaf.ju" | sed -n 's#.*/##;/.*usr.*/p'
fffusr
dfusrd
```

Comment: i thought the same, but i have tons of file and this solution is really slower compared to a regex search, thanks anyway

Comment: What do you mean by regex-search? sed does regex-search. Which tool(s) do you have? Today, every language has regex. I simplified it a bit - now it just uses sed, not grep.

Answer (score 0):

answer in javascript

```
var s = "/usr/etc/var:/etc/aaaaaf.ju"
s ; //# => /usr/etc/var:/etc/aaaaaf.ju
var last = s.match(/[^/]+$/);
last ; //# => aaaaaf.ju
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using PCRE:**

```
$re = '/.+\/.*usr.*/i';

$string = '/usr/etc/blabla:/etc/bbb
/usr/etc/blabla:/etc/bffb.gh
/usr/etc/blabla:/local/fffusr
/usr/etc/blabla:/bin/dfusrd
/usr/etc/var:/etc/aaaaaf.ju';

$nMatches = preg_match_all($re, $string, $aMatches);
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => /usr/etc/blabla:/local/fffusr
            [1] => /usr/etc/blabla:/bin/dfusrd
        )

)
```